# Анимация обновления для конкретного View в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-animation

Возник следующий вопрос: возможно ли при вызове метода `notifyItemChanged()` в адаптере `RecyclerView` показывать анимацию обновления не всего элемента, а какого-то указанного `View` внутри него?

К сожалению, Google ничего мне конкретного не ответил, только указал на то, как можно отключить эту анимацию вообще. Честно говоря, с анимациями в Android я очень сильно не дружу, поэтому вопрос может быть решен элементарным способом. Далее - по сути.

Для примера, у меня есть элемент списка, который содержит внутри себя три `TextView` с различными числами. В данный момент я делаю таким образом:

```
items.get(position).updateNewCount(count);
notifyItemChanged(position);
```

Очевидно, вызывается стандартная "анимация мерцания" всего элемента. Как уже писал выше, хотелось бы чтобы эта анимация появлялась не на всем элементе, а только на нужном `View`.

Заранее спасибо за ответы.